# cordovaDialogs no return value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to run either

```
$cordovaDialogs.confirm('message', 'title', ['button 1','button 2'])
    .then(function(buttonIndex) {
```

or

```
 $cordovaDialogs.prompt('msg', 'title', ['btn 1','btn 2'], 'default text')
    .then(function(result) {
var input = result.input1;
```

as listed [here](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/dialogs/),
but the return value in the then callback is `undefined` for both cases. Any ideas / fixes here?

Comment: Does the title work when you change it or does it say `index.html`? It could be that the Cordova plugin is not being loaded correctly and that it defaults to the default JavaScript dialogs.

Comment: I see, I will have to check again. Thanks for the lead.

Answer (score 0):

I know you are trying to use `$cordovaDialogs` but maybe give `$ionicPopup` a try? I have had better luck with that plugin. It basically works the same way.

```js
$ionicPopup.confirm({
     title: 'Consume Ice Cream',
     template: 'Are you sure you want to eat this ice cream?'
   }).then(function(res) {
     if(res) {
       console.log('You are sure');
     } else {
       console.log('You are not sure');
     }
   });
```

Here is the docs for it: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/

If you still can't get it working, comment and we will figure it out. I have used both plugins and I prefer ionic-popup.

Comment: Thanks Austin, but the `$ionicPopus` are the ones I'm trying to replace with a more native look... They worked well, but now that I saw the dialogs they look better for UX.

Comment: Understood. Just wanted to make sure you knew the other option. Ok so lets figure out why Dialog is not working. can you run this:

`var confirm = $cordovaDialogs.confirm('message', 'title', ['button 1','button 2']);

 confirm.then(function(buttonIndex) {
      alert(buttonIndex);
    )};`